# Xamarin. WebView progres

Tags: android, ios, webview, xamarin

I want to implement a custom WebView progress bar for both Android and IOS versions.

I used Xamarin.forms for this.

But can't find any information how it can be done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `StackLayout` with `ActivityIindicator` and `WebView` as children and set it's visibility based on IsWorking property value which is set in `WebView.Navigating` and `WebView.Navigated` events. Your ViewModel has to implement `IOnPropertyChanged`.